# Showing a caret symbol in MATLAB plot axis

Tags: matlab, plot, symbols, caret

I want the axis to show x with a symbol like this.

[image: picture]

If I don't misunderstand the symbol name is caret.
Is there any way to show this x with caret. Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Matlab's built-in LaTeX interpreter:

```
xlabel('$\hat x$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')
```

Comment: Btw, I also want a subscripted s at the right-down side of x. I tried `xlabel('$\hat x$_s', 'Interpreter', 'latex')` and `xlabel('$\hat x$_s', 'Interpreter', 'latex')` but it didn't work.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Subscripts in LaTeX only work in math mode, and the dollar signs start and end math mode. Therefore you have to write `xlabel('$\hat x_s$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')`. For an introduction to LaTeX, see http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf